# Where to put custom CSS and Javascript in DSpace 7.0?

Tags: angular, dspace

In previous versions of DSpace using the Mirage2 theme, if I want to include my custom javascript, I just put it in the scripts directory and reference it in the `scripts.xml` file. When it comes to custom CSS, I just reference it using the `@import` directive in the `_style.scss` file. Now that DSpace 7.0 is using Angular framework, I would like to know where should I put my custom JS and CSS files. I would like to migrate some of my customizations from 6x to 7 such as collapsible/expandable table of contents and it requires custom CSS and JS.

I think in this [Use Interface Customization](https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC7x/User+Interface+Customization) guide, I have a hunch how to put my custom CSS but I don't know where to put my custom Javascript.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**

What I tried based on my search from the web particularly this: [How to use external JS files and JavaScript code in Angular 6/7](https://www.truecodex.com/course/angular-6/how-to-use-external-js-files-and-javascript-code-in-angular)

Since my external custom Javascript depends on JQuery, I installed it by running:

```
npm install jquery
```

After installing jquery, I created a `js` directory under the `[dspace-angular]/src/assets` directory and copied my external javascript there.

I then added them in scripts array in `[dspace-angular]/angular.json` file:

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "src/assets/js/jquery.cookie.js",
  "src/assets/js/jquery.treeview.js",
  "src/assets/js/sair.js"
]
```

For the custom CSS, I copied it in `[dspace-angular]/src/styles]` directory and reference it in the styles array in `angular.json` file:

```
        "styles": [
          "src/styles/startup.scss",
          "src/styles/jquery.treeview.css",
          {
            "input": "src/styles/base-theme.scss",
            "inject": false,
            "bundleName": "base-theme"
          },
          {
            "input": "src/themes/custom/styles/theme.scss",
            "inject": false,
            "bundleName": "custom-theme"
          },
          {
            "input": "src/themes/dspace/styles/theme.scss",
            "inject": false,
            "bundleName": "dspace-theme"
          }
        ],
```

Since some content of this CSS uses background images, I copied the images in `[dspace-angular]/src/assets/images` directory.

After I saved `angular.json` and issued the command `yarn start:dev`, I received an error:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/app/shared/empty.util.ts:1:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
                         ~~~~~~
src/app/shared/empty.util.ts:2:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/operators' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

at createTSError (C:\dspace-angular\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:434:12)
at reportTSError (C:\dspace-angular\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:438:19)
at getOutput (C:\dspace-angular\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:578:36)
at Object.compile (C:\dspace-angular\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:775:32)
at Module.m._compile (C:\dspace-angular\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:858:43)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1257:10)
at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\dspace-angular\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:861:12)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1125:19)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I issued the command `yarn install` and then `yarn start:dev` and it compiled successfully.

When I checked it in my browser, I can say that the CSS was loaded because I can see the background images applied in the list. Basically, the custom javascript that I included is just to have an expandable/collapsible table of contents found mostly on the collection and item pages.

As an example of what it looked like on version 6.3:

[image: DSpace 6.3]

And this is what it looked like after the steps I have done above:

[image: DSpace 7.0]

My custom javascript that made the list collapsible/expandable which is in the `sair.js` file contains just this code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tree").treeview({
        collapsed: true,
        animated: "medium",
        control:"#sidetreecontrol",
        persist: "location"
    });
});
```

I did not find any relevant error (to me) in my browser's console that would tell me what I am missing here. I mean if the jquery did not load correctly, then I would have a `reference not found` error right?

I also tried to include the external javascript in the `<head>` tag of `index.html` but I only got a blank page.

So my question now are:

- What am I missing?
- Do the steps I made above are correct? (i.e., can this be considered best practice?)
- Are there any alternative steps on using external javascript?

Comment: The entire DSpace 7 UI is TypeScript (which compiles into Javascript).  There are no "*.js" files in the new UI.  Instead, everything is a TypeScript file (*.ts).  

Keep in mind there is no direct migration from the old Mirage-base UI to the new UI. So, per the Upgrade Docs, you will NOT be able to simply copy over old DSpace 6.x CSS or JS files into the new DSpace 7 UI. You must start fresh with the new UI. https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC7x/Upgrading+DSpace#UpgradingDSpace-UpgradingtheFrontend(UserInterface)

Comment: @TimDonohue, thanks for the comment. I understand that there is no direct migration from the old UI to the new UI. Perhaps I should have used the word porting and not migration. I would like to 'port' my collapsible/expandable list feature to DSpace 7.0. I edited my question to show the steps that I have tried. If you have the time, would you mind if you can check it out to see what I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how to help with this. I've never tried to use JQuery within Angular.io.  That's a bit of an odd combo, as Angular itself (and the Bootstrap we use in DSpace) already has these "collapsible/expandable" list capabilities itself.

You might want to take a step back and look at doing this using Bootstrap or Angular, instead of trying to port one Javascript-based framework (JQuery) into another (Angular).

That's just my initial reaction here...I could be entirely wrong though. As I said I've never tried this. We also don't support JQuery by default in DSpace 7.